# How to Moq DataFactoryManagementClient in Nunit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

net core project. I have one method as below in my repository.

```
public DataFactoryManagementClient InitiateConnection(AuthenticationConfig authenticationConfig);
```

I am calling above method in my business layer.

```
 public async Task<List<MyList>> MyMethod(IEnumerable<FileEntity> fileEntities)
        {
            DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient = azureDataFactoryRepository.InitiateConnection(_authenticationConfig);
            //rest of the code
        }
```

Now I am writing unit test case for the above method.

```
[Test]
        public async Task Mytest()
        {
           azureDataFactoryRepository.Setup(
               x => x.InitiateConnection(
               It.IsAny<AuthenticationConfig>())).Returns(new DataFactoryManagementClient());
           //rest of the code
        }
```

In the above code I am returning new DataFactoryManagementClient() but it says error Datafactorymanagementclient.Datafactorymanagementclient(params DelegateHandler[])) inaccsible due to its protection level. So I am just confused whether I am doing right thing or not? can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can use `IDataFactoryManagementClient` as a return type from `InitiateConnection` method and in the setup (test method) you return the mock of `IDataFactoryManagementClient`?

Comment: hi thanks I changed to IDataFactoryManagementClient but now how can I mock IDataFactoryManagementClient ?

Comment: After changing to IDataFactoryManagementClient  my code works fine but coming to mock how can I do moq IDataFactoryManagementClient ?

Comment: var `dataFactoryManagementClientMock = new Mock<IDataFactoryManagementClient>();` and then in your setup pass the `dataFactoryManagementClientMock.Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IDataFactoryManagementClient` as a return type from `InitiateConnection` method and in the setup (test method) you return the mock of `IDataFactoryManagementClient` by following code:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Mytest()
    {
       var dataFactoryManagementClientMock = new Mock<IDataFactoryManagementClient>();
       azureDataFactoryRepository.Setup(
           x => x.InitiateConnection(
           It.IsAny<AuthenticationConfig>())).Returns(dataFactoryManagementClientMock.Object);
       //rest of the code
    }
```